# Browser-Sync Proxy Middleware

Tags: nginx, proxy, gulp, middleware, browser-sync

I have a question regarding proxy middleware

I initialize Browser-Sync like this :

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    files = [
        '**/*.php'
    ];
    browserSync.init(files,{
        open:false,
        port: 3000,
        ui: {
            port: 3000 + 1
        },
        proxy: {
            baseDir: "./",
            target : "http://example.com",
        }
    });
});
```

And I use nginx to proxy to http://127.0.0.1:3000

```
server {
    listen EXTERNAL_IP:80;
    server_name development.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

However browser-sync calls 127.0.0.1:3000 instead of http://development.example.com
How can I tell browser-sync that it should call http://development.example.com ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen EXTERNAL_IP:80;
    server_name development.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

It was actually a nginx thing :)